# Нужно ли ставить запятую в предложении: "...является актуальным(,) и, соответственно, работа является актуальной"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, ссп

Нужно ли ставить запятую в предложении:
***Таким образом, создание перечисленных выше методов является актуальным(,) и, соответственно, работа является актуальной?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, не нужно, потому что "таким образом" — общее вводное слово для двух предложений.

Мы знаем, что запятая в ССП не ставится, если части сложносочиненного предложения имеют общее вводное слово, общий обособленный член или общую, поясняемую ими, часть сложного предложения:

*Словом, время уже истекло и пора было уходить.

Вопреки предсказаниям синоптиков, небо уже прояснилось и дождь перестал.

Было у Анны необъяснимое ощущение: еще чуть-чуть и вся эта история кончится* (Щерб.).
*Останавливаться было нельзя: ноги засасывало и следы наливались водой* (Пауст.).